# Git commit appears twice in Github when it is amended

Tags: git, github

I have a commit with message `#1 an old message`

I made

```
git commit --amend -m '#1 a new message' # to change commit message
git push origin +master:master # to force the update
```

then in Github issue #1 I see both messages.

Is this an issue with git or Github?

Comment: The attachment of commits to issues is a GitHub feature, not a git one. You should [report this](https://github.com/contact).

Comment: It's a gitHub problem, as git is not an issue tracker